# hide/show multiple buttons with Select menu onChange

Tags: jquery, html, smarty

I am not sure if anyone can help me with this but I currently have a < select menu > with onchange that shows 2 different forms when toggle. problem is I also have an update button outside of the form and is trying to change the button as well when the form changes.

below is my codes. can anyone help me figure this out.

JavaScript:

Hide/Show

```
function changelocation(val) {
    var id = val;
    //alert(id);
    if (id == '1') {
        $('#tr_1').css('display', 'table-row');
        $('#tr_2').css('display', 'none');
    }
    if (id == '2') {
        $('#tr_2').css('display', 'table-row');
        $('#tr_1').css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

Display Save button out of Form

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#location1_update").click(function () {
            $("#location1").submit();
        });
    });

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#location2_update").click(function () {
        $("#location2").submit();
    });
});
```

buttons

```
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="location1_update" value="Update">
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="location2_update" value="Update">
```

< select menu > - using smarty note -- this works fine.

```
<select class="selmenu-wo" name="company_locations" onChange="changelocation(this.value)">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">{section name=r loop=$location1}{$location1[r].LOCATION}
&nbsp;&nbsp;{/section}</option>
    <option value="2">{section name=q loop=$location2}{$location2[q].LOCATION}&nbsp;&nbsp;{/section}
    </option>
</select>
```

Forms.

```
<form action="" id="location1" name="location1" method="POST">
<table  cellpadding="0" id="tr_1"  cellspacing="0">
<tr> <td><b>Name</b></td>

<input name="test" type="text" value="Test data">

</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<form action="" id="location2" name="location2" method="POST">
<table  cellpadding="0" id="tr_2" style="display:none" cellspacing="0">
<tr> <td><b>Name</b></td>

<input name="test2" type="text" value="Test data">

</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

the forms toggle fine but I would like it to show the button when toggle as well.
if I assign the same id to the form and button only the button toggles.

Comment: why not include the button inside the respective form?

Comment: do you want show location1_update and hide location2_update when value on select is 1?

Comment: I don't want to include it in the form because it does not look well, I have another table when I display the buttons. more like at the header of the page.

Comment: @user3401335 yea I want to hide location2 button when form 1 is selected and hide location1 when form 2 is selected

Comment: I did not understand very well...so you have one "select menu" with 2 or more values...when you select one of these values it shoud appear a form or another, according to the value selected in the "select menu"...could you be more specific about the buttons?

Comment: @prelite The buttons are located outside of the form at the top of the page. I would like to hide/show them when the forms are selected. see my message above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$("#location1_update").hide()
```

and

```
$("#location1_update").show()
```

for hide and show the button.
change this html whit id instead name

```
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" id="location1_update" value="Update">
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" id="location2_update" value="Update">
```

then the js could be

```
if (id == '1') {
    $('#tr_1').css('display', 'table-row');
    $('#tr_2').css('display', 'none');
    $("#location1_update").show();
    $("#location2_update").hide();

}
if (id == '2') {
    $('#tr_2').css('display', 'table-row');
    $('#tr_1').css('display', 'none');
    $("#location2_update").show();
    $("#location1_update").hide();
}
```

Comment: Perfect!. I am an idiot, should have figured this out by my self but thanks for the help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the same class to the buttons and form for example:

```
<input class="submit-button location1" type="submit" name="location1_update" value="Update">
<input class="submit-button location2" type="submit" name="location2_update" value="Update">

<form action="" id="location1" class="location1" name="location1" method="POST">
<form action="" id="location2" class="location2" name="location2" method="POST">
```

Then show/hide both of them like this:

```
function changelocation(val) {
    var id = val;
    if (id == '1') {
        $('.location1').show();
        $('.location2').hide();
    }
    if (id == '2') {
        $('.location2').show();
        $('.location1').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, works too, just had to add styles to display non on the second button if value is 1